# Alfresco Share: mass (bulk) update metadata

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Have anybody created a custom dialog or page in Alfresco Share to let users update one or more property values for several documents at once?

I'm going to implement such a functionality, but don't want to reinvent a wheel. So if a similar solution already exists - please let me know.

In more details, the solution as I see it would be:

1. User selects several documents/folders in a folder;
2. Clicks "Selected Items" -> "Edit properties"
3. A dialog is shown similar to standard Edit Properties dialog, with only properties shown which are available for all of selected documents/folders;
4. User changes some values, clicks Save and all documents get updated.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blogpost on this issue:

Basically it involves the following steps:

1. Create a new multiple-action as you suggest above.
2. In the action, assure all nodes are of same type, if so invoke the regular form for the first nodeRef in the list but with a new form-id (that you define in share-config-custom.xml). Also supply a list of the nodes you want to update.
3. Create a new edit-form template ftl that populates a hidden field with the nodeRefs to update.
4. Subclass the NodeFormProcessor on the repo-side to do the nodePersist in a loop for all supplied nodes.

For more details:

http://alfresco.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2014/06/25/bulk-edit-of-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not such an addon for Alfresco Share available yet - at least not publically.
Good Luck!